# Binding nested listviews to class

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding

This is my class:

```
 public class ZuResults
{
    public Direct_Matches[] direct_matches { get; set; }
    public int found { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }

    public ZuResults()
    {

    }
}

public class Direct_Matches
{
    public object[] data { get; set; }
    public string[] headwords { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string pos { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
}
```

This is the ListView to which I am trying to bind this class:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,50,0,0" x:Name="listZuResults"  
                     SelectionMode="Single" Background="White"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                     BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" BorderBrush="LightGray" Width="350">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Query" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Query" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtQuery" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding query, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Found" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Results found" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtFound" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding found, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12"/>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=direct_matches[1]}">
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" BorderBrush="LightGray" Width="350">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Metadata" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Metadata" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=metadata}">
                                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Pos" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Pos" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtPos" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding pos}" FontSize="12"/>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

When I set the ItemsSource of listZuResults in my MainPage.xaml code-behind, the only values that actually appear when I debug are those of txtQuery and txtFound. How do I display the rest of the data, for example 'pos' and 'lang'?

Comment: You don't need third nested `ListView` (`metadata` is not a collection). Copy `TextBlock` into second `ListView` and change `Text="{Binding pos}"` to `Text="{Binding metadata.pos}"`. When something is wrong observe "Output" window for binding errors.

Comment: That didn't work. Observed the following from "Output" window: Error:     BindingExpression path error: 'metadata' property not found on 'ReadAppDataFromJsonAsset.ZuResults, ReadAppDataFromJsonAsset, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='metadata.pos' DataItem='ReadAppDataFromJsonAsset.ZuResults, ReadAppDataFromJsonAsset, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='txtPos'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: I tried your xaml in new solution. It has way to many errors (`Grid` doesn't have `BorderThickness`, there are some strange references, you can't bind to `FontColor` because your class doesn't have it, etc.) to continue fixing it. Consider preparing [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: MCVE: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=82342255281DCCFC!35085&authkey=!APyWyoUndoTTHEA&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Got myself a solution! I changed Direct_Matches[] to List<Direct_Matches> and it worked! Thanks for all your help, Sinatr!